# Canvas image data on retina display (MPB)

Tags: javascript, d3.js, canvas, svg, retina-display

I've read multiple suggestions on the issue of canvas blurriness on retina displays (e.g. using the window.devicePixelRatio approach; [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/HTML-canvas-guide/SettingUptheCanvas/SettingUptheCanvas.html), [here](https://coderwall.com/p/vmkk6a/how-to-make-the-canvas-not-look-like-crap-on-retina) and also [here](https://bl.ocks.org/LuisSevillano/9ad9c025a1fd9e82df64203bb8969c3d)) but I haven't been able to apply the suggested solutions to my specific problem. The following script first creates a canvas with some random image data (which appear blurry), and then exports the image to a SVG element and rescales it (still blurry of course). I am using a MBP late 2016 with touch bar and safari. Any suggestions on how to avoid blurriness and achieve crisp edges? Keep in mind that the initial imageData should have a fixed width and height.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>

<body></body>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var width = 100;
    var height = 100;

    var canvas = d3.select("body").append("canvas");
    context = canvas.node().getContext("2d"),

    canvas
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .style("width", width + "px")
    .style("height", height + "px")

    //this is the part that should normally take care of blurriness 
    if (window.devicePixelRatio > 1) {
      var devicePixelRatio = window.devicePixelRatio || 1;
      var backingStoreRatio = context.webkitBackingStorePixelRatio ||
      context.backingStorePixelRatio || 1;
      var ratio = devicePixelRatio / backingStoreRatio;
      canvas
      .attr('width', width * ratio)
      .attr('height', height * ratio)
      .style('width', width + 'px')
      .style('height', height + 'px');
      context.scale(ratio, ratio);
    }

    var imageData = context.createImageData(width, height);

    for (var i = 0, l = 0; i<height; ++i) {
        for (j = 0; j<width; ++j, l += 4) {
            imageData.data[l+0] = Math.round( Math.random() * 255);
            imageData.data[l+1] = Math.round( Math.random() * 255);
            imageData.data[l+2] = Math.round( Math.random() * 255);
            imageData.data[l+3] = Math.round( Math.random() * 255);
        }

    }

    context.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
    var ImageD = canvas.node().toDataURL("img/png");

    var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg').attr('width', width*5).attr('height', height*5);
    svg.append("svg:image").datum(ImageD).attr("xlink:href", function(d) {return d})
                    .attr("height", height*5).attr("width", width*5)

</script>
```

Comment: why have you not been able to apply the suggested solutions to your specific problem?

Comment: well, the above script implements these solutions with no success

Comment: Retina has CSS pixels set to 2 physical pixels. Canvas resolution is set to CSS pixels. To fix set the canvas resolution to 2 times the canvas size. Get size via `const bounds = element.getBoundingClientRect();` then set canvas size to `canvas.width = bounds.width * 2` and `canvas.height = bounds.height * 2`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've finally found the solution. I use a combination of the following: window.devicePixelRatio for getting the retina pixel ratio, off-screen canvas taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46011894/canvas-image-data-opacity-on-top-of-canvas-shape), and then scaling up the context taken from [here](http://devlog.disco.zone/2016/07/22/canvas-scaling/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>

<body></body>

<script type="text/javascript">

    const width = 20;
    const height = 20;
    const scale = 10; // the higher the number the crisper the custom image

    var canvas = d3.select("body").append("canvas");
    context = canvas.node().getContext("2d");

    const ratio = window.devicePixelRatio || 1;
    canvas.attr('width', width * ratio * scale)
        .attr('height', height * ratio * scale)
        .style('width', width * scale + 'px')
        .style('height', height * scale + 'px');

    var imageData = context.createImageData(width, height);

    for (var i = 0, l = 0; i<height; ++i) {
        for (j = 0; j<width; ++j, l += 4) {
            imageData.data[l+0] = Math.round( Math.random() * 255);
            imageData.data[l+1] = Math.round( Math.random() * 255);
            imageData.data[l+2] = Math.round( Math.random() * 255);
            imageData.data[l+3] = Math.round( Math.random() * 255);
        }
    }

    const offCtx = canvas.node().cloneNode().getContext('2d'); // create an off screen canvas
    offCtx.putImageData(imageData, 0,0);
    context.scale(ratio * scale, ratio * scale);
    context.mozImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
    context.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;
    context.drawImage(offCtx.canvas, 0,0);

    //export image
    var ImageD = canvas.node().toDataURL("img/png");
    //load image
    d3.select('body').append('svg').attr("height", 500).attr("width", 500).append("svg:image").datum(ImageD).attr("xlink:href", function(d) {return d})
                .attr("height", 500).attr("width", 500);

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

### Image data is not context aware.

The code you had would work if you used the context to render, but you are writing pixels directly to a image buffer. This is not effected by the 2D context transform and hence your code does not scale up.

In you code the line

```
context.scale(ratio, ratio);
```

that scales up the canvas rendering does not apply to the imagedata.

#### Simple fix

A simple fix if you know the device is retina. It doubles the canvas resolution and then sets random pixels. To keep with your original code I set 2 by 2 pixels to the same random value. The blur will be gone but the random pattern remain the same.

```
const width = 100;
const height = 100;
const w = width;  // because I hate cluttered code
const h = height;

const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
document.body.appendChild(canvas);
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

canvas.width = w * 2;
canvas.height = h * 2;
canvas.style.width = w + "px";
canvas.style.height = h + "px";

const imageData = ctx.createImageData(w * 2, h * 2);
// get 32bit view of data
const b32 = new Uint32Array(imageData.data.buffer);
// this is the part that you need to change as the canvas resolution is double

for (let i = 0, l = 0; i< h; i ++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < w; j ++) {
        const idx = i * w* 2 + j * 2;
        b32[idx + w + 1] = b32[idx + w] = b32[idx + 1] = b32[idx] = (Math.random() * 0xFFFFFFFF) | 0;
    }
}

ctx.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
const ImageD = canvas.toDataURL("img/png");

const svg = d3.select('body').append('svg').attr('width', width*5).attr('height', height*5);
svg.append("svg:image").datum(ImageD).attr("xlink:href", function(d) {return d})
                .attr("height", height*5).attr("width", width*5)
```

Comment: the above script still produces blurry images. Moreover it changes the ratio of the image dimensions.

Comment: @spyrostheodoridis Sorry my bad should have `ctx.createImageData(w, h); `as `ctx.createImageData(w * 2, h * 2);` Though that does not explain the aspect. As for the VGA, you are adding the image as 5*width and 5*height, it will always be blurry if you don't match the physical pixel resolution