# Canvas image data opacity on top of canvas shape

Tags: javascript, canvas

In the following example I've set the opacity of every image pixel to zero. Why isn't the grey background rectangle visible and how can I achieve that? Am I missing something in the rendering process of the shape vs image data?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>

<body>
    <canvas id='myCanvas'></canvas>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var width = 500;
    var height = 500;

    var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas')
    context = canvas.getContext("2d"),

    canvas.width = width;
    canvas.height = height;

    context.fillStyle = "grey";
    context.fillRect(0,0,100,100);

    var imageData = context.createImageData(width, height);

    for (var i = 0, l = 0; i<height; ++i) {
        for (j = 0; j<width; ++j, l += 4) {
            imageData.data[l+0] = Math.round( Math.random() * 255);
            imageData.data[l+1] = Math.round( Math.random() * 255);
            imageData.data[l+2] = Math.round( Math.random() * 255);
            imageData.data[l+3] = 0;
        }

    }

    context.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`putImageData` will set the pixels on your context with the ones you passed in the ImageData.

If a given pixel is set to transparent in the ImageData, so will it be on the context after you put it.

To avoid this, you can use an ImageBitmap object, that you'll be able to draw on your context like an image,

```js
const ctx = c.getContext('2d');
ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
ctx.fillRect(0,0,30,30);
const iData = ctx.createImageData(300, 150);
// make the noise mostly transparent
iData.data.forEach((d,i,a)=>{
  a[i] = (i+1)%4 ? Math.random() * 255 : Math.random() * 125;
  })
createImageBitmap(iData).then(img => ctx.drawImage(img, 0,0));
```

```html
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
```

or use an off-screen canvas :

```js
const ctx = c.getContext('2d');
ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
ctx.fillRect(0,0,30,30);
const iData = ctx.createImageData(300, 150);
// make the noise mostly transparent
iData.data.forEach((d,i,a)=>{
  a[i] = (i+1)%4 ? Math.random() * 255 : Math.random() * 125;
  })

const offCtx = c.cloneNode().getContext('2d'); // an offscreen canvas
offCtx.putImageData(iData, 0,0);
ctx.drawImage(offCtx.canvas, 0,0);
```

```html
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
```